# How would I solve this level?

Tags: untrusted

There is no editable space in the code here, so I have no idea how you would get to the exit. There is apparently no way to the exit because of the trees blocking me.

Any help/suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Appears to be offtopic because it is about coding and not playing a game in the traditional sense.

Comment: Someone else asked a question like this though...
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163480/how-to-use-the-phone

Comment: The relevant meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7661/is-programming-in-a-game-on-topic-here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line `100` you can change the function tied to your phone (`Q` key)

Change it to `generateForest` and when you cannot progress towards the exit, hit `Q` to re-distribute the trees.  Continue doing this until you can reach the exit.

[image: Line 100]

Comment: Works great! 
I didn't even see that small black spot!

Comment: @Darakath Took me a while to find it as well.

Comment: It's easier to see when selecting all text IMO.